# Reshape numpy array from 3D to 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a an array that is of shape (5,2,1)

```
array([[[-0.00047776],
    [-0.00065181]],

   [[-0.00065181],
    [ 0.00130446]],

   [[ 0.00130446],
    [ 0.00151989]],

   [[ 0.00151989],
    [ 0.00121407]],

   [[ 0.00121407],
    [-0.00121259]]], dtype=float32)
```

I want to convert it to shape (2,5,1) like this

```
        array([

                [[-0.00047776], [-0.00065181], [ 0.00130446], [ 0.00151989], [ 0.00121407]], 
                [[-0.00065181], [ 0.00130446], [ 0.00151989], [ 0.00121407], [-0.00121259]]


            ])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every NumPy array has a natural 1D order to its items. This is the order that
you see when you
[`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel)
the array. Reshaping (with the default order='C') does not change the order of
the items in the array.  Therefore, `x.reshape(shape)` is the same as
`x.ravel().reshape(shape)`. The key take-away message here is that *an array
`y` is "reachable" via reshaping `x` if and only if `y.ravel()` equals `x.ravel()`*.

So consider the raveled (1-dimensional) order of the items in the given array and the desired array:

```
In [21]: x = np.array([[[-0.00047776], [-0.00065181]], [[-0.00065181], [ 0.00130446]], [[ 0.00130446], [ 0.00151989]], [[ 0.00151989], [ 0.00121407]], [[ 0.00121407], [-0.00121259]]], dtype=np.float32); x.ravel()
Out[21]: 
array([-0.00047776, -0.00065181, -0.00065181,  0.00130446,  0.00130446,
        0.00151989,  0.00151989,  0.00121407,  0.00121407, -0.00121259], dtype=float32)
```

versus

```
In [22]: y = np.array([ [[-0.00047776], [-0.00065181], [ 0.00130446], [ 0.00151989], [ 0.00121407]], [[-0.00065181], [ 0.00130446], [ 0.00151989], [ 0.00121407], [-0.00121259]] ]); y.ravel()
Out[22]: 
array([-0.00047776, -0.00065181,  0.00130446,  0.00151989,  0.00121407,
       -0.00065181,  0.00130446,  0.00151989,  0.00121407, -0.00121259])
```

Notice that the item order is different. Thus, to achieve the desired array, you must first (somehow) reorder the items in `x`. In this case [using `swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to swap the first and second axes does the trick:

```
In [23]: x.swapaxes(0,1)
Out[25]: 
array([[[-0.00047776],
        [-0.00065181],
        [ 0.00130446],
        [ 0.00151989],
        [ 0.00121407]],

       [[-0.00065181],
        [ 0.00130446],
        [ 0.00151989],
        [ 0.00121407],
        [-0.00121259]]], dtype=float32)

In [26]: np.allclose(x.swapaxes(0,1), y)
Out[26]: True
```

No reshape is necessary since `x.swapaxes(0,1)` already has shape (2,5,1).

Comment: Great answer and explains a lot. I appreciate it.